# sql join not showing some records

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to find all customers who have placed an order but there isn't a callback after their last order date.

My current query:

```
SELECT dbo.[Order].CustomerId, MAX(OrderDate) AS OrderDate, NextCallbackDate, UserName
FROM dbo.[Order] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT MAX(CallbackDate) NextCallbackDate, CustomerID 
                 FROM AccountCallbacks
                 GROUP By CustomerId
               ) callbacks ON callbacks.CustomerID = dbo.[Order].CustomerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.aspnet_Users users ON dbo.[Order].UserID = users.UserId
WHERE (PaymentTypeID IN (2, 3, 4, 6, 8)) 
  AND OrderDate >= NextCallbackDate
GROUP BY dbo.[Order].CustomerID, dbo.[Order].OrderDate,callbacks.NextCallbackDate, UserName
ORDER BY dbo.[Order].CustomerID
```

Tables:

AccountCallBacks:

```
[CallbackID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[UserID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[CustomerID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[CallbackDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[Enabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
[CallbackTimeID] [int] NULL,
[GaryCust] [bit] NULL,
[NotInterestedReasonID] [int] NULL
```

Order Table:

```
[OrderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CustomerID] [int] NULL,
[UserID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[OrderDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[PaymentTypeID] [int] NULL,
[PaymentStatusID] [int] NOT NULL,
[PaymentDate] [datetime] NULL,
[TransactionRef] [varchar](50) NULL
```

And the aspnet_Users table is the usual .net membership users table

**EDIT:**

Apologies! I never actual said what was wrong! My query doesn't give me what I'm expecting one of the rows of data for a particular CustomerID isn't in the result set. And no, there should always be at least one AccountCallbacks.CallbackDate for every CustomerID as I'm joining on the dbo.[Order] table and they wouldn't be in there without first ever being in the AccountCallbacks table.

Feel free to ask any other info, help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there guaranteed to be a callback for each customerID? If not, your "OrderDate >= NextCallbackDate" in your WHERE clause would eliminate those rows

Comment: What's wrong with your current query?   Are you getting an error?

Comment: I've updated my question! Thanks!

Comment: When you say "one of the rows of data" isn't in the results set, do you mean that a customerID isn't showing up or it's the wrong result for that customerID? If the former, the only reason that would occur is if it doesn't meet the criteria in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Hey, I mean there is a missing CustomerID in my result set but they do meet the criteria as far as I can see.